# Why directive is not working after page change? Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple youtube directive on one page and works fine. However, if i go to page 2 and then come back, the player doesn't show up any more. 
Am I missing something here, or I simply misunderstand how directives work ???

Here is the [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/MlWOT85X0cEbd9EZozYl?p=preview)

Directive

```
app.directive('youtube', function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",

    template: '<div></div>',

    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;

      $window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        player = new YT.Player(element.children()[0], {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
        });
      };
    },  
  }
});
```

Controllers and app routes

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 

function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
    templateUrl: 'page1.html',
    controller: 'firstCtrl'
  });

  $routeProvider.when('/view2', {
    templateUrl: 'page2.html',
    controller: 'secondCtrl'
  });
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view2'});
    }])

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Main Page"
})

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Page 1"
})

app.controller('secondCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Page 2"
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed and you will be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're injecting the youtube scripts into the page each time the `youtube` directive is instantiated, and then depending on the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` event to instantiate the player.

This means that the second time the directive is instantiated, `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` never fires (because the API was already in place from the first time.)

One way to avoid this is to have the `youtube` directive's link function check to see whether the youtube API was already injected, and reuse it if so:

```
  if (window.YT) {
    player = new YT.Player(element.children()[0], {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
    });     
  } else {
    // your existing code here
  }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/2gjSd7np8uKVi4YmreiU

(Alternatively, you can embed the youtube API directly as a normal `<script>` tag in your index.html instead of injecting it via javascript as part of a directive, so it will be ready for any directive that needs to use it).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: Cheers, happy to help!